# How to re-generate Node Object from database stored Serialized Node Data .. and then Save as New Node?

Tags: nodes

In Drupal 7, for some reason, i am storing some `serialize($node)` objects into Database. So these data in the database (in `text` column) are storing like:

```
O:8:"stdClass":47:{s:3:"vid";s:5:"78629";s:3:"uid";s:3:"523";s:5:"title";s:12:"Sync Node #6";s:6:"status";i:1;s:3:"nid";s:5:"77429";s:4:"type";s:4:"page";s:8:"language"; ..... etc
```

- Now how can i transform these data back into Drupal `$node` Object please?
- Then how can i `node_save($node)` (as new node) upon them? (What tricks will i need?)

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3):

> Now how can i transform these data back into Drupal $node Object please?

As said you can use the following code,

```
$node = unserialize($data);
```

---

> Then how can i node_save($node) (as new node) upon them? (What tricks will i need?)

You can null the nid, vid and use `node_save` to save it as a new node like this:

```
$node->nid = NULL;
$node->vid = NULL;
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on the serialized data.

Comment: Hmmm.. Then how please?

Comment: Like so: `$node = unserialize($data);` where `$data` is the string that is stored in the database.

Comment: But, i mean .. i can NOT `node_save($node)` it :/ (`Then how can i node_save($node) (as new node) upon them? (What tricks will i need?)`)

Comment: The node already has a nid and a vid. Upon saving, node 5 is updated. Call `unset($node->nid);` to remove the nid before saving it to create a new node.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get unserialize() to work, it always returns 'false'. So, my solution was to:

```
$nodearray = drupal_json_decode($response->data);

$node = new stdClass();
foreach ($nodearray as $key => $value)
{
    $node->$key = $value;
}

unset($node->nid);
unset($node->vid);
unset($node->path);
```

It's messy, but it ends up creating a new node object that can then be saved using node_save($node).

Frankly, this is messy, I would much prefer to have been able to use something like unserialize(). So if anyone has a hint as to why unserialize() is returning false for me, then please do let me know!